# Value of Non-ASCII characters readed from txt file by using "System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine" were modified by mistake

Tags: vb.net, hex

This looks a simple question, but I cannot find a good answer for it. 
What I am doing is I read one line of a text file, then parse it using string.substring(12, 6) to get the sub string, which is actually a piece of hex data. (It's a long story, why i get into this situation.) 
The following screenshot is how it looks like in NotePad++

[image]

The Hex value was not encoded by any way, just using each char present a number. I would like to convert this string to a hex array. During testing I found most of the char can be converted to hex correctly. But some of them were wrong.
[image]

For example in the attached pic, I want to parse and get string of "00 00 02 87 50 0C". Then convert this string into hex array [0][0][0][0][0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVg5G.jpg)[8][7][5][0][0][C]. But the hex value "87" cannot be converted correctly.

After get a deeper look, I found it's caused by ReadLine(). During readline(), those non-ASCII characters was not being kept with original values. I did a test to read all lines one by one from input file, then write them  into an output file. I can see those not-ASCII characters were changed to something else. 
The code I used to read file is:

`Dim fileInput As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("d:\temp\xyz.txt")`

`Do While fileInput.Peek() <> -1`

```
      `Dim oneLine As String = fileInput.ReadLine()`
```

... blabla

```
loop
```

So is there any way to read string line by line without change those non-ASCII character by mistake?

Thanks

Comment: If you want Byte values then read then as a Byte array.  You can convert a byte to a hexadecimal string using the "X2" format specifier.

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. What is the encoding of your text file? If you don't know, you have a failed communication. But, perhaps you aren't dealing with text at all. If not, you shouldn't be using text functions and datatypes. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Thanks Tom, i mentioned in my questions ((It's a long story, why i get into this situation.) The file suppose is a TEXT file, but with some hex value in it  without any encoding. They are just numbers saved in each char using hex value. For example in the screenshot, i need to parse the hex value in the green box, then get/convert it to a number 0000028750. But I get difficulty at very beginning. When I parse the substring, the value was modified by "ReadLine".

Comment: The screenshot of Notepad++ that you show does not match the second screenshot.  The first screenshot shows a date of 20140828 but the second screenshot shows 20110822.  Can you show screenshots that match?  What encoding is Notepad++ using?  Look down in the lower right corner of Notepad++ and it should show the encoding it is using (probably UTF-8).  Make sure that you open the file using the same encoding.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I have update the screen shoot and highlighted the area i got issue. So far, i believe the Readline() is over smart to read text file line by line, and modified the non-ASCII to character to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to read some bytes from a file, after some number of lines, as binary, into a byte array.

Since your data is line-oriented with 0d 0a line-endings, it makes some sense to read it as text. However, since it also contains binary, you have to read it with an encoding that allows all byte values 0-255 in any order.

UTF-8 is the default for System.IO.StreamReader. It does not meet this requirement because it does not allow arbitrary ordering of all values. (It encodes some Unicode codepoints into multiple 8-bit code units and they have a particular pattern.)

You could use CP437. It allows all values 0-255 in any order and 0d is CR and 0a is LF so it is compatible with the line-endings in your data. It also encodes all characters in 1 byte.

So read to the line you want. Skip to the character position you want and take the substring to the characters that your binary data decoded to, then re-encode as CP437 to get the bytes back.

```
Dim encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(437)
'…
' get your line
Dim binaryDecodedAsCp437 = onelineDecodedAsCp437.substring(12, 45)
Dim byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(binaryDecodedAsCp437)
```

Since you are encoding back and forth with CP437, the original bytes will be restored.

Answer (score 1):

`StreamReader` is not a good choice for a file containing a mix of text and binary data because it will try to interpret the binary portion as encoded text, when in fact it is just binary data.

Try using `BinaryReader` instead. If you have a fixed record size (and it appears that you might), then you can use `ReadBytes()` to read one record at a time, like so:

```
    Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream("d:\temp\xyz.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Using br As New BinaryReader(fs, New ASCIIEncoding())
            Dim record(recordsize) As Byte
            record = br.ReadBytes(recordsize)
            While record.Length > 0
                ' Get an ASCII text string from the byte array
                Dim field1 As String = Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(record, 18, 8)

                '...Do something with the binary data

                record = br.ReadBytes(recordsize)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
```

If the record size is variable, and delimited by `\r\n` then it is going to be a little more work. One option would be to extend `BinaryReader` by adding a `ReadLine` method like [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339311/ReadLine-on-Binary-Stream).